# Content Delivery Java API 2013SP1 objectcache Tomcat does not shutdown

Tags: 2013, java

We use the Java content delivery API on Tridion 2013SP1 with `ObjectCache` enabled. When running as a Java web application on Tomcat 7, we notice the Tomcat server will hang on shutdown when we have the `RemoteSynchronization` section in the configuration.

Removing the `RemoteSynchronization` from the configuration, or setting `ObjectCache/@Enabled` to false, will allow Tomcat to shutdown normally. The application calls `StorageManagerFactory.closeStorageManagerFactory()` prior to servlet container shutdown, but without effect. Tomcat will not shutdown other than if we kill the process. Has anyone overcome experienced this issue, and solved it?

Attached is my config file fragment (cd_storage_conf) :

```
<ObjectCache Enabled="true">
  <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">
    <Param Name="MemSize" Value="32mb"/>
  </Policy>

  <Features>
    <Feature Type="DependencyTracker" Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker"/>
  </Features>

  <RemoteSynchronization Queuesize="2000" ServiceMonitorInterval="10000"
                         FlushCacheDuringDisconnectInterval="60000">
    <Connector Class="com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector" Topic="Tridion">
      <JndiContext>
        <Property Name="java.naming.factory.initial"
                    Value="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
        <Property Name="java.naming.provider.url"
            Value="tcp://${jms.host}:${jms.port}?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=60000"/>
        <Property Name="topic.Tridion" Value="${jms.topic}"/>
        <Property Name="userName" Value="${jms.user}"/>
        <Property Name="password" Value="${jms.password}"/>
      </JndiContext>
    </Connector>
  </RemoteSynchronization>
</ObjectCache>
```

Comment: Hi Kees.. Welcome to Tridion stack exchange, and thanks for asking a good question. I've edited it a bit - among other things to make the XML easier to read. I had to add a closing tag to your Features element, so perhaps you should just check that the XML in your storage conf is well-formed/valid, and if not, fix it and re-test.

Comment: Hi Dominic, thank you. My XML is well defined, and all works well except shutting down the application server.

Comment: Good - it was worth checking, though.